# ag-grid : Disable cell edit on key press and pro grammatically enable row edit with edit button (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2

I have a edit button on each row and I have set

```
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: false,
  }
```

in the grid options

I want the row to be in edit mode when I click on edit button. My edit button works fine if I set

```
  defaultColDef: {
    editable: true,
  }
```

But it enables keypress edit which I don't want to.

How should I dynamically edit that particular row without setting the editable to true in my `defaultColdef` ?

On click of edit, I have enabled the `this.gridOptions.defaultColDef.editable = true`,  but no luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While defining the columnDefs , give  `editable: false`

On clicking the edit button, for dynamically editing the particular Column/Cell in row use:

```
this.GridOptions.columnApi.getColumn('employeeName').getColDef().editable = true;
```

And after finishing the editing use:

```
 this.GridOptions.columnApi.getColumn('employeeName').getColDef().editable = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement onCellClicked method of ag-grid to listen to the click event on your edit button and then use startEditing method to start editing of the corresponding row. Sample code follows:

```
onCellClicked(value): void {
    if (value.colDef.colId === '<YOUR_EDIT_BUTTON_COL_ID>') {
        this.gridOptions.api.startEditing({
            rowIndex: value.rowIndex,
            colKey: '<col_id_of_first_editbale_col_in_the_row>'
        });
  }
}
```